# How to change text every 5 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a line of text, with a span. I wanted to the text in span change every 5seconds.
I made a script :

```js
var texts = new Array();
texts.push("Text1");
texts.push("Text2");
texts.push("Text3");

var point = 0;

function changeText(){
  $('#cookie-alert .col h3 span').html(texts[point]);
  if(point < texts.length){
    point ++;
  }else{
    point = 0;
  }
  setInterval("changeText", 5000)
}

changeText();
```

So the array contains all the texts.
So with this, the first text appears but not others.
I have an error:

> "ReferenceError: changeText is not defined" at line "setInterval("changeText", 5000)"

I don't understand where is my mistake

Comment: try `setInterval(changeText, 5000)` Pass it as function and not a text

Comment: Don't work, same error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to pass the `changeText` as a function and not a text.
2. You have to call `setInterval` outside the fuction `changeText`
3. As suggested, need to use `texts.length - 1` coz you start counting from 0.

```js
var texts = new Array();
texts.push("Text1");
texts.push("Text2");
texts.push("Text3");

var point = 0;

function changeText(){
  $('#cookie-alert .col h3 span').html(texts[point]);
  if(point < ( texts.length - 1 ) ){
    point++;
  }else{
    point = 0;
  }
  
}
 
setInterval(changeText, 5000); /*Call it here*/
changeText();
```

Comment: @sinisake You are correct. Added on the answer. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

`setInterval` takes as its first argument the function, not the function's name as string like this:

```
setInterval(changeText, 5000)
```

But you really should be using `setTimeout` in the function like this:

```js
var texts = new Array();
texts.push("Text1");
texts.push("Text2");
texts.push("Text3");

var point = 0;

function changeText(){
  $('h3').html(texts[point]);
  if(point < texts.length - 1){
    point ++;
  }else{
    point = 0;
  }
  setTimeout(changeText, 5000)
}

changeText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> </h3>
```

or simply `setInterval` like this:

```js
var texts = new Array();
texts.push("Text1");
texts.push("Text2");
texts.push("Text3");

var point = 0;

function changeText(){
  $('h3').html(texts[point]);
  if(point < texts.length - 1){
    point ++;
  }else{
    point = 0;
  }
}
changeText();
setInterval(changeText, 5000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3> </h3>
```

Edit: To work flawlessly you wanna have the if be `if(point < texts.length - 1)` so it repeats at the same rate.

Comment: Yeah thank you, first solution work. But i want to replay this when the last word is showing...

Comment: Note that I updated my answer to include a fix for the counter. And also if an answer solved your problem you can accept it by checking the checkmark on the left - this will give you rep a +2 boost.